# Eclipse/ZEND PHP always returns 500 server error

Tags: php, eclipse, debugging, zend-framework, internal-server-error

Strangest thing, every script I run returns 500 server error.

Even this in a otherwise blank file in a brand new PHP project:

```
<?php echo "1"; ?>
```

This just suddenly happened, no configuration changes. No errors in the PHP error log, in Eclipse or in the PHP server (ZEND's viewer). I restarted the computer just in case. Another project I have in the same workspace seems to run fine without 500 errors?

I had been playing around with returning different response codes (putting together a REST API) but I can't see how anything I did in a PHP script would be permanently changing the response header of all scripts in all new projects everywhere forever. Javascript calls to the script get the same error (but sees the 1);

The above does return the 1, but the header in the eclipse debug output says:

```
Status: 500 Internal Server Error
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.14 ZendServer
Set-Cookie: ZDEDebuggerPresent=php,phtml,php3; path=/
Set-Cookie: ZendDebuggerCookie=192.168.1.120%3A10000%3A0||00C|77742D65|1000; path=/
Content-type: text/html

1
```

Comment: Check the error log of the webserver. 500 Error is an error foremost by your webserver, you find more information in that logfile.

Comment: maybe .htaccess file incorrect created by your ide?

Answer (score 0):

Delete this file, and recreate it using filezil